# Hasura: How to filter a subquery with non relationed fields?

Tags: graphql

I have this complex query and I need to filter `alumnos_regulares` table with related fields and a non-related field `id_alumno` from `alumnos` table.

```
query MyQuery($_carrera: bigint = "", $_insti: bigint = "", $_materia: bigint = "", $_eq: bigint = "", $_eq1: bigint = "") {
  alumnos(where: {alumnos_x_carreras: {id_carrera: {_eq: $_carrera}, institucion: {_eq: $_insti}}}) {
    id_alumno
    apellido
    nombre
    dni
    alumnos_x_carreras {
      carrera {
        id_carrera
        institucion
        materias(where: {id_materia: {_eq: $_materia}}) {
          id_materia
          materia
          correlativasregularsByIdMateria {
            id_carrera
            id_materia
            id_correlativa
            materia {
              materia
              alumnos_regulares(where: {id_alumno: {_eq: alumnos.id_alumno ??????? }) {
                id_alumno
                id_materia
                id_mat_reg
              }
            }
          }
          correlativasdebilesByIdMateria {
            id_carrera
            id_materia
            id_matc
            materia {
              materia
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to make this filter?